# Change User Email Address without notifying olduser

Tags: email, user

I am the Admin of my developer org and i have configure 5 user over there and i want to change Email address of one of the user without any notifying them i mean through mail.

is it possible in the salesforce???

Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: Hello team is it possible or not let me know

Comment: Do you want to prevent the email being sent to the old email address or to the new email address?

Comment: i just want to prevent the email being sent to the old user.....

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can do this. There are 3 steps to this:

1. Prevent emails from going out. This  can be done by going to `Setup -> Administer -> Email Administration -> Deliverability` and  setting the `'Access Level'` dropdown to `'No access'`. Don't forget to Save.
2. Update the email addresses of the users. This can be done by going to the User detail screen and changing the email address. But **don't forget to also check the "`Generate new password and notify user immediately`" checkbox** at the bottom of the screen. That way the email address will be changed immediately, without asking for a confirmation by email (because that email will not be sent, i.e. you just disabled it in step 1).
3. Reactivate the emails that you disabled in step 1.

Comment: I confirm this works. +1

Comment: no longer working

Comment: Hi @HO LI Pin. This stil seems to be working for me. The only scenario in which it doesn't work is if you try to do this for your own user.

Comment: i see , it wont work if i am the 1 , 10q ! i flagged your solution up vote .

Comment: For anyone else misreading the question like I did: note this only blocks the email to the old address, not the new one!

Answer (score 2):

We achieved this in the following way and it worked very well.

1. Edit user detail page, make sure the user is active
2. Change user email address.
3. Add mobile number
4. Check the checkbox "generate password and inform user immediately"
5. Save the user record

This send a reset password email to the email address. When user clicks on the link the verification page appears. the verification code is sent on user's mobile number instead of old email address.

To receive verification code on mobile number please check if following setting is there:

1. go to Setup-->identity verification
2. Enable checkbox 'Let users verify their identity by text (SMS)' and 'Prevent identity verification by email when other methods are registered'
3. Disable the checkbox 'Require identity verification for email address changes'