# Mass change sandbox emails without confirmation

Tags: sandbox-refresh

How can I change User email's in a sandbox back to their production email in bulk?

e.g. `mary=company.com@example.com` to `mary@company.com`

We have several hundred users and would like to refresh the sandbox monthly. We use SAML single sign-on so passwords are not important. We have automated processes using the email, so even if the user doesn't login it is useful to have the correct email address.

Can Apex mimic [changing the email + generate new password](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/77394/53148)?

Comment: Changing the email via Apex doesn't work - or more specifically it sends a confirmation email and waits for user to accept.

Answer (score 1):

This help article should help you : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Disabling-Email-Change-Verification&language=en_US&type=1

A System administrator or any designated contact needs to open a case with salesforce support.

Hope this helps.