# How to bypass "Email Verification" in Salesforce during email value update action

Tags: email, user-management, user-record

I have already read [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387986&type=1) document and refer below questions in this website but still I have wonder if any other workaround available to update the active users's email (valid email) into ***".invalid"*** format in Salesforce Sandbox org without notify the user.

Question 1: [Change User Email Address without notifying olduser](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72578/change-user-email-address-without-notifying-olduser) (`why not tried means, I can't update the "Deliverability" settings of my Org due to it's affects the other email sending functions.`)

Question 2: [Update user email without email confirmation via Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/344139/update-user-email-without-email-confirmation-via-apex) (`I can't find any solutions in this question`)

Because sometimes after the sandbox testing completed, As an admin I need to update the user's email again into invalid for rectify the other testing Emails are not disturbed into users due to this valid email address.

Any helps appriciated!!!

Thanks.